# I need to learn some expressions

Tags: phrases

I saw this short sentence in the Merriam Webster.

"slopes off into the night"
— Wolcott Gibbs

What does "slopes off into the night" mean in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Context is needed.  Peter’s answer is possible, but I think a ski slope at night lit only around the lodge at the top could also be described as sloping off into the night.

Answer (score 1):

The *Merriam-Webster* dictionary doesn't really give a good explanation of this.

From the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slope)

> *British, informal* **slope off:** Leave unobtrusively, typically in order to evade work or duty.
>   *‘the men sloped off looking ashamed of themselves’*

So it means to leave unobtrusively, under the cover of darkness.